# Building Cassandra PDO driver failing

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, thrift

I am trying to install the PDO extension for Cassandra but everytime i try the make command i get this error:

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -Wall -Wno-write-strings -I. -I/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/include -I/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/main -I/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/thrift -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/cassandra_driver.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/cassandra_driver.o
In file included from /home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/php_pdo_cassandra_int.hpp:45,
                 from /home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/cassandra_driver.cpp:18:
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4289: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4289: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4291: error: cannot declare pointer to 'void' member
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4291: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4291: error: template argument 4 is invalid
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4292: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4292: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4293: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4293: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4294: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4294: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4295: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4295: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4296: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4296: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4297: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4297: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4298: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4298: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4299: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4299: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4300: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4300: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4301: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4301: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4302: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4302: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4303: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4303: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4304: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4304: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4305: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4305: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4306: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4306: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4307: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4307: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4308: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4308: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4309: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4309: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4310: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4310: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4311: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4311: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4312: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4312: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4313: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4313: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4314: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4314: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4315: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4315: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4316: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4316: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4317: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4317: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4318: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4318: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4319: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4319: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4320: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4320: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4321: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4321: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4322: error: 'org::apache::thrift' has not been declared
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4322: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: 'thrift' is not a member of 'org::apache'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: 'thrift' is not a member of 'org::apache'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: 'thrift' is not a member of 'org::apache'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: 'thrift' is not a member of 'org::apache'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4359: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h: In constructor 'org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::CassandraProcessor(boost::shared_ptr<org::apache::cassandra::CassandraIf>)':
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4326: error: assignment of read-only location '"login"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4326: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4327: error: assignment of read-only location '"set_keyspace"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4327: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4328: error: assignment of read-only location '"get"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4328: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4329: error: assignment of read-only location '"get_slice"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4329: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4330: error: assignment of read-only location '"get_count"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4330: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4331: error: assignment of read-only location '"multiget_slice"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4331: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4332: error: assignment of read-only location '"multiget_count"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4332: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4333: error: assignment of read-only location '"get_range_slices"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4333: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4334: error: assignment of read-only location '"get_indexed_slices"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4334: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4335: error: assignment of read-only location '"insert"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4335: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4336: error: assignment of read-only location '"add"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4336: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4337: error: assignment of read-only location '"remove"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4337: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4338: error: assignment of read-only location '"remove_counter"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4338: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4339: error: assignment of read-only location '"batch_mutate"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4339: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4340: error: assignment of read-only location '"truncate"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4340: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4341: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_schema_versions"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4341: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4342: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_keyspaces"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4342: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4343: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_cluster_name"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4343: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4344: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_version"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4344: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4345: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_ring"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4345: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4346: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_partitioner"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4346: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4347: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_snitch"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4347: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4348: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_keyspace"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4348: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4349: error: assignment of read-only location '"describe_splits"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4349: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4350: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_add_column_family"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4350: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4351: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_drop_column_family"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4351: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4352: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_add_keyspace"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4352: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4353: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_drop_keyspace"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4353: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4354: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_update_keyspace"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4354: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4355: error: assignment of read-only location '"system_update_column_family"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4355: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4356: error: assignment of read-only location '"execute_cql_query"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]'
/home/ec2-user/cassandra-pdo/gen-cpp/Cassandra.h:4356: error: cannot convert 'void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int)' to 'const char' in assignment
make: *** [cassandra_driver.lo] Error 1
```

I installed thrift with these commands:

```
tar -xzvf thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz
sudo mv thrift-0.8.0 /opt/thrift-0.8.0
chown brian /opt/thrift-0.8.0
cd /opt/thrift-0.8.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then i tried to install cassandra-pdo with these commands:

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/
sudo chown -R brian cassandra-pdo
cd cassandra-pdo/
phpize
./configure
make
```

but then that last make returns the above error.

Comment: Try installing with Thrift version 0.6.x

Comment: Tamil is correct, the driver is written against Thrift 0.6, so I suspect that's what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all of the dependencies and build dependencies besides Thrift can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev php5-dev libpcre3-dev pkg-config g++
```

If you are using Debian or Ubuntu, you can use the proper repository by adding the following entry to ***/etc/apt/sources.list***:

```
deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main
sudo wget -O - http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | apt-key add -
```

You can then install the Thrift packages with the following:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install libthrift0 libthrift-dev thrift-compiler
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/thrift /usr/local/bin/thrift
```